# How to apply/reload X settings after changes to xorg.conf.d configuration files

Tags: xorg

I have added a synaptics.conf file under /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf. Do I need to restart X to see it applied?

Comment: You can try out your settings by starting a new X with `startx` if you have a correct .XClients / .xinitrc, that is, there is a program at the end that keeps X running. Usually the program is a window manager (like /usr/bin/fluxbox) but I just entered /usr/bin/xterm. `xset q` might show you some values. Switch between the running X servers with ctrl-alt-F<n> (e.g. ctrl-alt-f7).

Comment: thx for these details

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes. X.Org's configuration files are only read when the server is started.

Comment: Here are ways to restart X: http://askubuntu.com/questions/131051/how-to-kill-and-to-start-the-x-server